# Can Somebody help me understand this query

Tags: mysql, query

The below SQL query gets all the ids which have different last names.

```
select *
from names a
WHERE a.first_name in (
select b.first_name 
  from names b
  WHERE a.last_name<>b.last_name
)
```

I am not able to figure out how this exactly works. What I thought would happens is,
for every row in the table the subquery will check if there exists  a row with a different last name. But the checking happens among only  identical values of first name. Can someone explain how this actually works.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: "Find first_names that are paired up with different last names."

Answer (score 3):

The SQL given is an example of a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

It is *correlated* because there is a reference to the outer table inside the subquery.

Some people find this form more intuitive than writing the equivalent join or `EXISTS`. Others find it a bit weird and more difficult to think about.

SQL often allows us to write the same logical query specification in different ways. Given a good optimiser, which you choose comes down to a question of style. Not all optimisers are good.

In this case, the correlation is the reference to `a.last_name`. This makes the result of the subquery *dependent* on the 'current row' from the outer query.

Essentially, the query is asking for rows where the `first_name` attribute matches any row (from the same table) where the `last_name` attribute is different.

In other words, people who share a first name but not a surname.

You could write the same requirement as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM names AS a
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM names AS b
    WHERE b.first_name = a.first_name
    AND b.last_name <> a.last_name
);
```

Some people might find that easier to read than the `IN` subquery form. It does make it easier to see there are two tests involved, perhaps.

See [13.2.11.7 Correlated Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) in the reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

> The below SQL query gets all the ids which have different last names.

**No it doesn't**.

> Why the query in the question doesn't return all the names which have
> different last names?

Because it doesn't take in consideration same names.

In simple words in the example below, which are the names that have different last names ?

Answer. `John and Anna.`

You are selecting the rows with `first_name in (John,Anna)` , but with this condition the rows `John    Smith` and `Anna    Smith` are returned.

Follow below example:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
`first_name` VARCHAR(15),
`last_name` VARCHAR(15) );

INSERT INTO names VALUES
('John','Smith'),
('John','Test2'),
('Anna','Maria'),
('Anna','Smith'),
('Ron','Smith'),
('Maria','Smith');
```

Based on the `SQL query gets all the ids which have different last names.` the query in the question  must return only below values,

```
first_name  last_name
John    Test2
Anna    Maria
```

but it doesn't, it gives:

```
first_name  last_name
John    Smith
John    Test2
Anna    Maria
Anna    Smith
```

> Why is wrong result returned ?

When you need to select names which have different last names you have to use a condition where last_names count is equal to 1.

Maybe you are trying to use:

```
select * 
from names 
where last_name in ( select last_name
                     from names
                     group by last_name
                     having count(*) = 1
                   )
```

which will return only the names that doesn't share last_names

Check the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05486412d013c13424650bd8cd59bcac).